# Returning pages with stack navigation routes

Tags: flutter, dart, routes

I'm developing an application for making quotes in Flutter and Dart and I have the following page stack:

-> RegistrationBudgetPage (click on the include button and open the includesItemPage)
-> IncludesItemPage (it has the Search Items button, where I open the ItemPage)
-> ItemsPage (the itemsPage is opened, a card is selected by the gestureDetector, and this card loads the data of the selected item in the IncludeItemPage)
-> IncludingItemPage (returns to IncludingItemPage, where the data for the selected item was loaded into the respective fields).

My problem is, when I get to the last IncludingItemPage, the data has already been loaded into the fields, and I want to abandon the operation and go directly back to the CadastroOrcamentoPage by clicking on the icon to go back, I can't go directly, as I need to unstack all the pages that were open until reaching the desired one, then it occurs when the return IncludeItensPage (current) -> ItemsPage -> IncludeItensPage -> CadastroOrcamentoPage.

How can I fix this?

I'm using Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) => Page(parameter if any),),);

I tried using named routes but it ends up making it a little difficult due to the parameters. Would it be possible for me to fix it the way I'm using it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use popUntil:

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) {
  return route is MyMainMenuRoute || route.isFirst;
});
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html

Comment: after two days trying to figure out how to get to the page I wanted by going through the stack pages, I managed to use Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed(route); The main error I was having is that I was using a MaterialApp() in the body of one of my pages. After removing it, I managed to fix it. Thanks for the answer! It helped me research other ways to manipulate stacking.